# Google app shouts whenever I get a call

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I don't know what setting I have done but every time I get a call, my google app starts shouting "Call from.." how to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

i am mobile technician at Samsung, we do get lots of phones with these problem and it is a simple solution to it. please try tapping 3 to 4 times on home button, that disables the voice command.